# Wubi won't boot after a kernel update

Tags: wubi, bootloader, windows-vista

I use Windows Vista 32bit and have a Wubi install of the 10.10 RC. It worked great, until one day when I upgraded the kernel and rebooted.

Now, whenever I select Ubuntu from the Windows boot menu, the screen goes black for half a second and I am returned to the boot menu. Is there a way to repair this?

Comment: It might be related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/15353/update-destroyed-grub/15412#15412 .

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is no visible activity or information added to it for several months. I have flagged a moderator and am voting for it to be closed. If you feel that the question is not abandoned and that you still suffer from this issue please flag a moderator so that it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too and someone else just complained of the same problem. I think this is a general bug of wubi. I think you should now install directly to the hard disk. Since the purpose of wubi is not for long term use but for testing purposes(not totally).

Comment: I'd love to repartition the hard drive, but that's not an option in my current environment.

Comment: How about a virtual machine?